# How could I count dates based on some condition?

Tags: r, date, count, lubridate

I have two date variable one is question open date and another is question answered date, like follows:

```
   q_open     q_answer
2020-09-01   2020-09-02
2020-09-01   2020-09-09
2020-09-05      NA
2020-09-10   2020-09-17
```

I need to find out the counts of the question that are not answered within a week. The week starts from the min(q_open). So week one starts from 2020-09-01 and ends on 2020-09-07.
So the desired output is:

```
Week   count_answered
 1         2           # considering NA also
 2         1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  q_open = as.Date(c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-09-05", "2020-09-10")),
  q_answer = as.Date(c("2020-09-02", "2020-09-09", NA, "2020-09-17"))
)

out <- data %>%
  mutate(wk_open = week(q_open),
         wk_answer = week(q_answer)) %>%
  mutate(on_time = ifelse(wk_answer >= wk_open + 1, TRUE, FALSE )) %>%
  group_by(wk_open) %>%
  summarise(count_answered = sum(on_time, na.rm = TRUE))
```

with:

```
> out
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  wk_open count_answered
    <dbl>          <int>
1      35              2
2      36              0
3      37              1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the week number subtracting `q_open` value from the minimum value, get the difference between answer date and `q_open` date in weeks, keep the rows which are greater than 1 week and `count` them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(week_num = as.integer(ceiling(pmax(q_open - min(q_open), 1)/7))) %>%
  filter(difftime(q_answer, q_open,units = "weeks") >= 1 | is.na(q_answer)) %>%
  count(week_num)

#  week_num n
#1        1 2
#2        2 1
```

**data**

Assuming the columns are of date class. If they are not run `df[] <- lapply(df, as.Date)` first.

```
df <- structure(list(q_open = structure(c(18506, 18506, 18510, 18515
), class = "Date"), q_answer = structure(c(18507, 18514, NA, 
18522), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```